# Adobe ExtendScript keep hyperlink page after changing document path

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm trying to merge multiple Indesign documents and having problems with keeping the hyperlinks. The documents have external page hyperlinks and after merging I have to change the destination to the merged document. So I've created a little script that checks all hyperlinks and sets their documentPath to the current file. But the page from this hyperlink is lost after this. So I'm trying to save the page to a variable before changing the documentPath. But I can't set the destinationPageIndex with the variable. If I check the variable it has the right value, but setting it doesn't work, the hyperlink resets to page 1. If i just set destinationPageIndex = 20 for example it sets all links correctly. So it just ignores the page variable.
It seems like a simple problem but I seem to miss something.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var hyperlinks = doc.hyperlinks;

for (i = 0; i < doc.hyperlinks.length; i++){
    var hyperlink = hyperlinks[i];
    var destination = hyperlink.destination;
    
    if (destination instanceof HyperlinkExternalPageDestination) {      
        var page = destination.destinationPageIndex;
        destination.documentPath = doc.fullName.absoluteURI;

        destination.destinationPageIndex = page;
        //destination.destinationPageIndex = 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell `ExternalPageDestination` destination doesn't work inside the document. You have to change the type of the destination to `PageDestination` if you want to make it work inside the current document.

Something like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var hyperlinks = doc.hyperlinks;
var hyperlink = hyperlinks[0];
var destination = hyperlink.destination;
var page = destination.destinationPageIndex;

// create a new destination of the type 'PageDestination'
var new_destination = doc.hyperlinkPageDestinations.add();

// set the desired page
new_destination.destinationPage = doc.pages[page-1];

// assign the new destination
doc.hyperlinks[0].destination = new_destination;

// note: hyperlink.destination = new_destination; <-- won't work
```